# Video Recording with Face detection parllely in android

Tags: java, android, face-detection, video-recording

My need is: If user is recording a video from my app then face detection should work. I mean during video recording if user is too far from camera or too close to camera and so on.. then i should alert him/her for improper position.

I did some R & D on it but unable to found desired example. 
What i found is, we can not perform both operation parallel on same View.

If any body have solution for my problem then please share. Please don't suggest openGL. I dont want to use it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wondering if you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513379/how-to-record-screen-and-take-screenshots-using-android-api

Comment: Did you find any solution?@rahul-gupta

Comment: @NitinKhanna - I think We need to work with 2 video mode in which one mode will record the video and other one will detect the face. This is my theory. But there is one more issue that either we can use two mode for recording video and detection or not?

Comment: @RahulGupta Thanks for quick response. Well, actually I'm able to apply color filters while recording but in case of face detection It doesn't work. It skips face position view while recording.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's MOBILE VISION API for face detection .

check [here](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial) for documentation and check [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)  for sample source code , application using this api .

some basics creating detector

```
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder()
        .build(getApplicationContext());

detector.setProcessor(
    new MultiProcessor.Builder<Face>()
        .build(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory()));

//Create a camera source to capture video images from the camera, 
    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder()
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build(getApplicationContext(), detector);
```

Comment: Thanks Omar, currently i am using the same method. This method is helping me to detect the face and working fine. But i am unable to record the video with face detection in parllel by using this method.

Comment: Where is video recorded in this answer?

Comment: Hi all, Are you able to detect face and recording video parallelly?

Comment: @RahulGupta Any update?

Comment: @NitinKhanna -  No update.