# how to record a particular view of an activity without using projection manager

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to record texture changes of a particular `view` in android. i have used `Projection Manager` to record my screen, but this will record all the activities on the screen including incoming notifications and all. Is there any way to record a particular `view` of a screen without using `Projection  Manager`, please help me to find an answer for this.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513379/how-to-record-screen-and-take-screenshots-using-android-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record screen and take screenshots, using Android API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513379/how-to-record-screen-and-take-screenshots-using-android-api)

Comment: @Lekr0 This is not the answer am seeking for, I wanted to understand is there any other way to record a particular view of an activity, all the texture changes on that particular view. The question which you have mentioned on SO doesn't fulfill my question ( It is by using slandered android projection manager - it will annoy the user ). Please reconsider your comment with a proper answer

Comment: @IshaanJavali Please check my last comment