# Record canvas animation as a realtime video on android

Tags: android, video-capture, android-mediarecorder

I have my app where I draw on SurfaceView programmatically. I want to record that animation as a video (mp4). Is there a way to do this?

I checked the MediaRecorder, but it can record only camera output. Is it possible to give a canvas/SurfaceView as a media stream?
I don't like to use  MediaProjection it's not limited to my app but the whole phone screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513379/how-to-record-screen-and-take-screenshots-using-android-api

Comment: isnt it using MediaProjection. That's not what I want. It shows permission dialog and also records whatever on-screen not limited to my view.

Comment: Is this approach helpful? https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java