# Prevent MediaProjection object from being lost on killing the Application

Tags: android, singleton, android-mediaprojection

I am using MediaProjection to take screenshot.This is what I am doing.I created an overlay icon using service.On clicking the overlay icon a screenshot is taken.The problem is that whenever the Application is killed either by pressing back button or manually by swiping it the MediaProjection object is lost.Is there a way to maintain the MediaProjection and avoiding requesting for MediaProjection each time application is killed. I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398211/how-do-i-get-a-media-projection-manager-without-disturbing-the-current-foregroun) but I am still unable to do it.

In my Mainactivity Onclick contains startActivityForResult and the resulting onActivityResult is as follows:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,final int resultCode,final Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == requestcode)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Singelton.setScreenshotPermission((Intent) data.clone());
            Singelton.putmanger(mediaProjectionManager);

        }else if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Singelton.setScreenshotPermission(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The Singelton class is as follows:

```
protected static void setScreenshotPermission(final Intent permissionIntent)
{
    screenshotPermission = permissionIntent;
//screenshotPermission becomes null once the application is killed
}

public static MediaProjection getData()
{
    return (mediaProjection);
}

public static void getScreenshotPermission()
{
    if (screenshotPermission != null)
    {
        Log.d("screenshotpermisson", "screenshotPermission != null ");
        if(mediaProjection!=null)
        {
            Log.d("mediaprojection", "mediaprojection != null ");
            mediaProjection.stop();
            mediaProjection = null;
        }
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(Activity.RESULT_OK, (Intent) screenshotPermission.clone());
    }
   else
    {
    //Here I need to request for media projection again without starting activity
    }

}
```

My Service class for overlay icon handles click as follows:

```
 public void createDisplay()
{
    if (mediaProjection == null)
    {
        Singelton.getScreenshotPermission();
        mediaProjection = Singelton.getData();
    }

    mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 1);
    vd = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("screen-mirror", width, height, mDensity, DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, null);
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener(){..}
}
```

I am new to android and having a hard time figuring this out.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: An app moving to the background isn't necessarily killed. It might be killed to free up memory, or it might sit quietly until it's un-paused. Is there a reason why you can't release the media projection at pause time, and recreate it at resume?

Answer (score 1):

Just re-create the media projection as fadden implied in his comment. Since every time your service is killed the associated overlay is also killed with it therefore you have to re-create the media projection anyway when restarting the service.

You already doing fine by not consuming the original intent and instead using an clone as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892817/3918978 .

However if the permission or the MediaProjection shouldn't be valid anymore just get a new one (start an activity asking for it).