# How to use MediaProjection to capture screen in a Service?

Tags: android, service, capture, android-mediaprojection, mediaprojectionmanager

As we know, we can use Android MediaProjection API to capture screen in an Activity, but I want to capture screen in a thread of a Service. But Android Service has no onActivityResult() method that MediaProjection need to do something. It seems that we can only call MediaProjection API like belows:

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
```

Is there a way to use MediaProjection in an Android Service?

Comment: My App has no Activity but only a Service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a media projection manager without disturbing the current foreground process, except to ask for permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398211/how-do-i-get-a-media-projection-manager-without-disturbing-the-current-foregroun)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381455/android-mediaprojectionmanager-in-service#32849121